Mistake in solution to show that $\frac{x^ay}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ if $a>1$.
I was working through some practice problems, and I'm not sure where I'm wrong in the following proof.

The function $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{x^ay}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
    0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0) \\
\end{cases}
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is some fixed number.
Prove that if $a>1$, then $g$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

What's wrong with my proof here:
Let $c=(0,0)$, $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \varepsilon^{a-1}$. Then, when $0<||x-c||<\delta$, we have that
$|g(x)-g(c)| = |\frac{x^ay}{x^2+y^2}|=\frac{|x^ay|}{x^2+y^2} \leq\frac{|x^ay|}{x^2}=|x^{a-2}y| < \delta^{a-1} = \varepsilon$ (Because $|x|,|y| \leq ||\textbf{x}|| < \delta$)
What goes wrong when trying to apply this to $a \leq 1$? Thanks.

Your argument only works if $a\geq 2$.
The mistake lies on the step $$|x^{a-2}y| < \delta^{a-1} $$
The fact that $|x|<\delta$ does not imply that $x^{a-2}<\delta ^{a-2}$, because the function $f(x)=x^{a-2}$ is increasing if $a-2\geq 0$ and decreasing if $a-2<0$.
For a correct proof, you may use the inequality $x^2+y^2\geq |2xy|$ (which follows because $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0$).
Using said inequality, we get $$|g(x,y)-g(0,0)| = \left|\frac{x^ay}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{|x^ay|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \dfrac{|x^ay|}{|2xy|}=\dfrac{|x|^{a-1}}{2}$$
As $a>1$, $x^{a-1}$ is increasing, so taking $||(x,y)||<\delta<(2\epsilon)^{a-1}$ we get $|g(x,y)-g(0,0)|<\epsilon$, as desired.
